# Get checkbox attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

For example I have several checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="27" name="option_value[12][]" id="option_value_27"  class="filtered option_value" cat="121">
<input type="checkbox" value="27" name="option_value[12][]" id="option_value_27"  class="filtered option_value" cat="141">
```

Two questions:

1. Is the declaration of `cat` attribute valid?
2. How can I get access to `cat` attribute value for example when I click on button?

Comment: Don't be fooled, `data-*` attributes are only valid if you plan to use an HTML5 doctype. Having said that, your example really sucks – `value`s and `id`s are the same

Answer (score 9):

No, `cat` is not a valid attribute, you can use HTML5 `data-*` attributes and jQuery `data` method:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="27" name="option_value[12][]" id="option_value_27"  class="filtered option_value" data-cat="121">
```

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    var cat = $('#option_value_27').data('cat');
})
```

Or `attr` method:

```
var cat = $('#option_value_27').attr('data-cat');
```

Or if you are not using jQuery, you can also use `dataset` property:

```
var cat = document.getElementById('option_value_27').dataset.cat;
```

Also note that IDs must be unique. If you want to get the values of all `cat` attributes, you can use the `map` method:

```
var cats = $('.filtered').map(function(){
    return this.dataset.cat
    // or $(this).attr('data-cat')
}).get()
// console.log(cats)
```

Now `cats` is an array of all the values of `data-cat` attributes.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Can I use a class selector - for example var cat = $('.filtered').attr('data-cat'); for getting all checked values?

Comment: Can I use a class selector - for example var cat = $('.filtered').attr('data-cat'); for getting all checked values?

Comment: @Spider84 You can use class selector which is good, but `attr` returns a attribute value of the first selected element, you can use `map` method, I'll update the answer.